# using jQuery post with php

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have this code jQuery/php:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#editorForm").submit(function(){
            alert('json');
            var dataString = $("#editor1").val();
            var id=1;
            $.post('/DataTransfer/EditContent.php?id='.id, { data: dataString}, function(res){
                alert(res);
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                $("#dataContainer").html(obj.data);
                $("#ckContainer").hide('slow');
                $("#dataContainer").show('slow');
                $("#modifica").html('Modifica');
            }, "text");
            return false;
        });


});
```

and a server side EditContent.php like this:

```
    <?php
        include_once("../Classes/HtmlHelpers.php");
        include_once("../Classes/DbHelpers.class.php");
        $link=dbHelpers::OpenConnection();
        $pageId=$_GET["id"];
        $data= $_REQUEST['data'];

          $sql = "UPDATE `ghionet2_Common`.`Pages` SET `PA_INNER_HTML` = '$data' WHERE `Pages`.`PA_ID` = $pageId;";
          $result=mysql_query($sql, $link)or die("errore: ".mysql_error());
          $retdata= array( 'sql'=>$sql,'id'=>$pageId, 'data'=>$data);
          dbHelpers::CloseConnection($link);
          echo $_GET['callback'] .json_encode($retdata);
?>
```

What's wrong? why $retdata return all calling page html like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>

<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<meta name="description" content="Home Page"/>

<meta name="keywords" content=""/>

<title>Home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/jQuery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Index.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="banner">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://free.netsons.com/free728x90.php?i=341463"></script>

</div>

<div id="header">

<div id="memberInfo">

<strong> Benvenuto admin!</strong> | <a class="iframe" href="ChangePassword.php">Cambia Password</a> | <a href="LogOut.php">Esci</a></div>

</div>

<div id="menu">

</div>

<div id="main">

<div id="content">

<div id="dataContainer">

<p>
...
```

Comment: This kind of question is universally frowned upon in stackoverflow, we are not here to do the work for you :) we are here to help you, please rephrase and and ask somethinkg specific, I sure someone can / will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are actually posting to the page and it is not just returning your 404 page because it cannot find it?

Comment: yes, i'm sure the return code is exactly html code of my page